# Auto resume downloads in Firefox

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-quantum

I tried to use some plugins ([auto resume downloads](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/auto-resume-downloads/?src=api), [Download Auto-Resume](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-auto-resume/)), but it don't work or not compatible with my Firefox (Firefox Quantum 57.0 x64).

I can resume download by clicking the button (↻ see below). But how to do it automatically?

*P.S. Sorry for my English. It's not my native language.*

[image: Falied download screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume downloads that are interrupted when using **Firefox** you should consider using [Download via IDM (Internet Download Manager)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-via-idm/?src=hotness) which works in conjuction with [Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/).

> *[**Internet Download Manager**](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) (IDM) is a tool
>   to increase download speeds by up to 5 times, resume and schedule
>   downloads. Comprehensive error recovery and resume capability will
>   restart broken or interrupted downloads due to lost connections,
>   network problems, computer shutdowns, or unexpected power outages.*

---

### Further Resources

- [Download Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Download_manager)
- [Comparison of download managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers)